# How to ignore or hide same values when a dropdown list is created from a database?

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu

I am populating a dropdown list using a database records.
Following code creates a perfect dropdown list using my databse records:

```
<div class="from-city">
    <label for="from-city">From City</label>
    <?php
        $query = "select id, fcity from tour_package";
        $result = $con->query( $query );

        echo '<select name="from-city" id="from-city">';
        echo '<option value="">--select--</option>';
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['fcity']; ?>"><?php echo $row['fcity']; ?></option>
        <?php    
        }
        echo "</select>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Issue is I have many packages with same `fcity`
What I mean is:
package1, package2, package3 all three's fcity is same. Let's say it is NY
When I create `fcity` dropdown list I am getting NY in the dropdown list THREE TIMES because I have NY as `fcity` for three packages.

I want to ignore the list option if it is has the same value which is already used to create the list option.
So basically no duplicate values/options in the dropdown list.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't need id of a package you can just use the following query:

```
$query = "select distinct fcity from tour_package";
```

This will give you all distinct cities in your table. 
And you can place'em in a select with the same code you've already have.

Comment: A keyword that helps to select all distinct values of a column in your table.

Comment: distinct is a keyword used in sql query.

Comment: that works perfectly... thanks.. Just now I've remembered what I learned about distinct in college days..